# IMU and rosserial

Tags: ros, arduino, imu, message, rosserial

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I'm using the arduino with rosserial and my code is the simplest one possible :

```
#include <ros.h>
#include <ros/time.h>
#include <sensor_msgs/Imu.h>

ros::NodeHandle  nh;

sensor_msgs::Imu imu_msg;
ros::Publisher pub_imu( "/imu", &imu_msg);
char frameid[] = "/imu";

void setup() {  
Serial.begin(57600);

nh.initNode();
nh.advertise(pub_imu);
imu_msg.header.frame_id =  frameid;
imu_msg.header.stamp=nh.now();
}


void loop() {

 pub_imu.publish(&imu_msg);
 nh.spinOnce();
}
```

And when I run it, I have that kind of error :

```
[INFO] [WallTime: 1395754919.360506] ROS Serial Python Node
[INFO] [WallTime: 1395754919.372573] Connecting to /dev/ttyUSB0 at 57600 baud
[INFO] [WallTime: 1395754921.671875] Note: publish buffer size is 280 bytes
[INFO] [WallTime: 1395754921.672177] Setup publisher on /imu [sensor_msgs/Imu]
[ERROR] [WallTime: 1395754921.673737] Message from device dropped: message larger than buffer.
```

So I can see that the message is considered too big by the PythonNode but it's empty and I'm using the standard IMU message. I'm using the Arduino duemilanove.
How can I reduce the size of the message ?

[EDIT]

After some test, it mostly come from the fact that it's an IMU message. If I use a range type for example, it works. Is it just impossible to send IMU message type through libserial ? Should I use 3 Publisher to transport the message and create a node that send a Imu_msgs type after ?

Thanks a lot.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/144056/imu-and-rosserial/) by [Maya](https://answers.ros.org/users/12786/maya/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1172 on 2014-03-25

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [colidar](https://answers.ros.org/users/42343/colidar/) on 2019-06-17**:
Thanks for sharing your code! Which imu are you using?
I want to use my MPU9250 with arduino uno with rosserial but i dont geht any imu values when i check rostopic echo /imu. Do you know why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Did you consider increasing buffer size? See this question & answer http://answers.ros.org/question/73627/how-to-increase-rosserial-buffer-size/

---

Originally posted by [Wolf](https://answers.ros.org/users/4478/wolf/) with karma: 7555 on 2014-03-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Maya](https://answers.ros.org/users/12786/maya/) on 2014-03-25**:
Thanks a lot that was exactly what I was searching for !